# Introspecting IDENTITY columns

Tags: sqlanywhere

For a table such as:

```
create table foo (id int identity primary key)
```

I would like to query the system tables to determine that `id` is in fact an `IDENTITY` column.

The closest thing I found was:

```
select tc.max_identity from systabcol tc
join systab t on t.table_id = tc.table_id
where t.table_name = 'foo'
```

Unfortunately `max_identity` is `0` even for columns which are not identities, and is also `0` for identities which haven't been used yet. Would have been nice if it was `NULL` for non-identities.

I can use the `GET_IDENTITY` function to check if a table has an `IDENTITY` column, but then I lose an identity value and I still don't know which column it is.

Any help much appreciated, this is the last thing I need for basic SQL Anywhere support in DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader in 0.05002 .

Answer (score 1):

[SyBooks Online](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.tables/html/tables/tables22.htm) note the status column. This is ASE, but it might be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can use the "default" column in SYSTABCOL:

```
select tc.[default]
from systabcol tc
join systab t on t.table_id = tc.table_id
where t.table_name = 'foo'
```

when the "default" column is set to 'autoincrement' then it's an IDENTITY column.